# Need to calculate the percentage of distribution

Tags: math, average, distribution

I have a set of numbers for a given set of attributes:

```
red    = 4
blue   = 0
orange = 2
purple = 1
```

I need to calculate the distribution percentage. Meaning, how diverse is the selection? Is it 20% diverse? Is it 100% diverse (meaning an even distribution of say 4,4,4,4)?

I'm trying to create a sexy percentage that approaches 100% the more the individual values average to the same value, and a lower value the more they get lopsided.

Has anyone done this?

Here is the PHP conversion of the below example. For some reason it's not producing 1.0 with a 4,4,4,4 example.

```
$arrayChoices = array(4,4,4,4);

foreach($arrayChoices as $p)
    $sum += $p;

print "sum: ".$sum."<br>";

$pArray = array();

foreach($arrayChoices as $rec)
{
    print "p vector value: ".$rec." ".$rec / $sum."\n<br>";
    array_push($pArray,$rec / $sum);
}   
$total = 0;

foreach($pArray as $p)
    if($p > 0)
        $total = $total - $p*log($p,2);

print "total = $total <br>";

print round($total / log(count($pArray),2) *100);
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple, if rather naive, scheme is to sum the absolute differences between your observations and a perfectly uniform distribution

```
red    = abs(4 - 7/4) = 9/4
blue   = abs(0 - 7/4) = 7/4
orange = abs(2 - 7/4) = 1/4
purple = abs(1 - 7/4) = 3/4
```

for a total of 5.
A perfectly even spread will have a score of zero which you must map to 100%.
Assuming you have `n` items in `c` categories, a perfectly uneven spread will have a score of

```
(c-1)*n/c + 1*(n-n/c) = 2*(n-n/c)
```

which you should map to 0%. For a score `d`, you might use the linear transformation

```
100% * (1 - d / (2*(n-n/c)))
```

For your example this would result in

```
100% * (1 - 5 / (2*(7-7/4))) = 100% * (1 - 10/21) ~ 52%
```

Better yet (although more complicated) is the [Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%E2%80%93Smirnov_test) with which you can make mathematically rigorous statements about the probability that a set of observations have some given underlying probability distribution.

Comment: Thank you! This was great. I nearly had it. :)

Answer (score 1):

One possibility would be to base your measure on [entropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_%28information_theory%29#Definition).  The uniform distribution has maximum entropy, so you could create a measure as follows:

1) Convert your vector of counts to `P`, a vector of proportions
    (probabilities).

2) Calculate the entropy function `H(P)` for your vector of
    probabilities `P`.

3) Calculate the entropy function `H(U)` for a vector of equal
    probabilities which has the same length as `P`. (This turns out
    to be `H(U) = -log(1.0 / length(P))`, so you don't actually
    need to create `U` as a vector.)

4) Your diversity measure would be `100 * H(P) / H(U)`.

Any set of equal counts yields a diversity of 100.  When I applied this to your (4, 0, 2, 1) case, the diversity was 68.94.  Any vector with all but one element having counts of 0 has diversity 0.

ADDENDUM

Now with source code!  I implemented this in Ruby.

```
def relative_entropy(v)
  # Sum all the values in the vector v, convert to decimal
  # so we won't have integer division below...
  sum = v.inject(:+).to_f

  # Divide each value in v by sum, store in new array p
  pvals = v.map{|value| value / sum}

  # Build a running total by calculating the entropy contribution for
  # each p.  Entropy is zero if p is zero, in which case total is unchanged.
  # Finally, scale by the entropy equivalent of all proportions being equal.
  pvals.inject(0){|total,p| p > 0 ? (total - p*Math.log2(p)) : total} / Math.log2(pvals.length)
end

# Scale these by 100 to turn into a percentage-like measure
relative_entropy([4,4,4,4])     # => 1.0
relative_entropy([4,0,2,1])     # => 0.6893917467430877
relative_entropy([16,0,0,0])    # => 0.0
```

Comment: I'd love to see an example in code of this technique based on the values above. Looks interesting.

Comment: @MarkLöwe There you go.

Comment: I'm having trouble converting your ruby code. Could you look at my php example above?

Comment: The division by `log2(arraylength)` is done after all the terms have been totaled, not term-by-term.

Comment: I think I finally got! Thank you brother.

Comment: It's ideal...simple...and easy to maintain. Thank you again.